# RTSP streaming in android

Tags: android, rtsp, live-streaming

Here is my code, and when I run the app, it will display "Sorry this video cannot be played".

```
public class rtspActivity extends Activity {

    Button btn;
    VideoView v;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rtsp);
        v=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vv);

        v.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://server.intelcast.tv:554/live/haditvfour1"));

    }

 }
```

Comment: @ShreyaShah in this issue, no Logcat will be there.

Comment: Please mention which device you're testing it on. A few months ago [I couldn't run this code on Samsung Galaxy S2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715702/cannot-play-rtsp-video-in-videoview-in-samsung-galaxy-s2)! All the other devices, even the emulator could run it.

Comment: i am checkin on sony ericsson xperia x10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start with

```
v.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
v.requestFocus();
v.start();
```

Also, the url you're using might not be good. Try it in VLC or similar, to see if its actually there

Another problem can be the "server.intelcast.tv:554" part, try replacing this with a real ip adress with numbers, i've experinced this issue myself

Comment: can you give me the link for testing